# Is there an isomorphism between these two finitely generated modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring and $M$ a finitely generated module over $A.$ Then $M = Aw_1 + \ldots + Aw_s.$ When exactly is there an isomorphism between $M/Aw_s$ and $Aw_1 + \ldots + Aw_{s - 1}.$ Intuitively, to me, these two should be isomorphic. I guess the most natural way to define a map would be to send $a_1w_1 + \ldots + a_{s - 1}w_{s - 1} + Aw_s \mapsto a_1w_1 + \ldots + a_{s - 1}w_{s - 1}.$ However, I d0n't think this is even well defined. When exactly can we form an isomorphism between these two modules? My guess is when $w_1, \ldots, w_{s - 1}$ is linearly independent...

Comment: You have this isomorphism when $Aw_s \cap \sum_{i=1}^{s-1} Aw_i = 0$ (which is sort of saying $w_s$ is independent from the other $w_i$'s); otherwise, the map is not well-defined.

Comment: I mean the map you defined above, btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any case, there exists a canonical morphism $A w_1 + \cdots + A w_{s-1} \hookrightarrow M \to M / A w_s$ in the other direction.  Moreover, it is easy to see that this map is surjective in general.  However, the kernel of this map is exactly $(A w_1 + \cdots + A w_{s-1}) \cap A w_s$ which is not zero in general; but if it is zero, then yes, the two modules are isomorphic.